# Exception in thread ArrayIndex

Tags: java, arrays

I was doing some beginner programming with series and input but im having the same problem constantly.Cant find the solution.Basically what i want my program to do for now i input a list of numbers and print them out.And im getting the same error over and over whatever i change in program.Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test437 {  
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int limit = 25;
  int cnt; 
  int addtion; 
  double dbt; //Devided by two % 2

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
  int [] ya = new int[8]; 

  for(cnt = 0;cnt < ya.length;cnt++)
  {

      System.out.print("ya[" + cnt + "]= ");
      ya[cnt] = input.nextInt();

  }

      System.out.println(ya[cnt]);


  }
  }
```

Im getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
        at Test437.main(Test437.java:22)

Comment: I am not getting any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
System.out.println(ya[cnt]);
```

needs to be in a loop again to print out all the array values after accepting them:

```
for (cnt = 0;cnt < ya.length;cnt++) {
   System.out.println(ya[cnt]);
}
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ya));
```

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ya));

I think im going to start using this one :D

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(ya[cnt]);` this line is outside loop. `Cnt` is equal to an array size so it cannot be used in such way because there is no element in the array with such index.

Answer (score 0):

cnt condition to leave the loop is to exceed the length therefore you get in indexoutofbounds

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
        System.out.println(ya[cnt]);
```

is trying to access element at ya.Length index which does not exists.

In your example ya[8] contains elements at position from 0  to 7 (ya[0] ya[1] ... ya[7] and you're trying to access ya[8] bacuase cnt variable is 8 after the for statement ends.

Therefore the compiler throws an indexOutOfBounds exception.